# Use Laravel as a webservice and client

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-5.4

Is this possible to use laravel framework on one side as a RESTful webservice and on other side as a client ? 
I have a project thats has a internal database. And on other side a web application. I would like to make a REST API for the internal db and consume it with laravel framework as a client. So there will be 2 laravel projects.

Comment: it is possible, to be a client, you could throw [curl](https://packalyst.com/packages/tag/curl) into it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Is simple to create a [restfull controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).
To create a client you can use something like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)
Or anything you want

Comment: can i use guzzle as a extension for laravel framework ? or is this a standalone solution ?

Comment: Yes, instal with composer in your project http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html#installation

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible. PHP gives you a number of ways to make HTTP requests, the most powerful of which is probably [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). I recommend you use [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) as that will make your life a lot easier.